# AudioKit using AKSequencer GenData & LoadMIDIFile

Tags: swift, audiokit

I'm using AKSequencer's genData function to receive the MIDI in file format. I would next like to use that MIDI file that I generate to load it into a AKSequencer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. AudioKit's [MIDIFileEditAndSync](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/develop/Examples/iOS/MIDIFileEditAndSync) example shows both how to create a new `AKSequencer` from a MIDI file using `loadMIDIFile()` and how to add the tracks from a MIDI file to an existing `AKSequencer` using `addMIDIFileTracks()`.  Of course the output of the `genData` method can be used to do either.

Comment: I've seen that example and it's very useful in this case. I only have one issue with loadMIDIFile, when I genData and write it to the disk it works fine and well but then when I try to loadMIDIFile using the URL I get the error message "error reading midi file url: {URL}", "status: -1".

Comment: I'd make sure that your URL is okay. Can you get loadMIDIFile to work with the URLs for other (non-genData exported) MIDI files?  Anyway, running the example project, you can clearly export a file with genData and load the exported file back in with loadMIDIFile.